Find an empirical formula that relates the output voltage of a solar panel to irradiation and temperature
I want to determine the output voltage of a solar panel based on irradiation and temperature.
I have a dataset spanning three years of irradiation and temperature in Dubai, recorded every 30 minutes.
Using machine learning, I've predicted future features. Now, I aim to calculate the output voltage for each 30-minute interval based on irradiation and temperature.
I'll then compare it with the minimum input voltage of the inverter. If the output voltage is smaller, I'll switch between panels (we have 500 panels) to adjust the input voltage of the inverter.
I have all the necessary parameters of the panel.

So you have the data, now come up with the empirical formula... Asking us to give you a wild guess without any data is unlikely to produce much.
